# React router dom v6 'Link' component issue with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I have a component which contains a `Link` component from react router dom `v6`.

MyComponent.jsx

```
...

<Link to='/path'>
   Som Text
</Link>

...
```

But if I try to render this component using react testing library.

```
render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <MyComponent />
    </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

I get this error - **`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createHref').`**

I have tried removing `Link` from the component and just replacing it with `div`. The error goes away so it means it is coming from the `Link` component.

Answer (score 0):

Many unit test environments tend to be non-DOM environments, so using the `BrowserRouter` might not be the best choice of router to use. The [`MemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router) is ideally suited for non-DOM environments.

> A `<MemoryRouter>` stores its locations internally in an array. Unlike
> `<BrowserHistory>` and `<HashHistory>`, it isn't tied to an external
> source, like the history stack in a browser. This makes it ideal for
> scenarios where you need complete control over the history stack, like
> testing.

In your unit tests for components that ***require*** a routing context be provided to them, e.g. components that render `Link`s and `Route`s, you should import and wrap these components with the `MemoryRouter`.

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<MemoryRouter>
  <MyComponent />
</MemoryRouter>
```